# scopes of list or arrays in python when renewed

Tags: python, arrays, list, scope

at this code I found when just line #1 is running (line #2 is commented)  the tcheck2 function can change the list x but when it renewed `x=[[] for _ in range(3+1)] #2` in line #2  nothing happens to x at tcheck1 function, why is that?

```
def tcheck():
    x=[11,54]
    tcheck2(x)
    print(x)
def tcheck2(x):    
    print(x)
    x[0]+=1 #1
    x=[[] for _ in range(3+1)] #2
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? And what is  `q`?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: @S3DEV sorry that is print.

Comment: [This video might be of interest](https://youtu.be/_AEJHKGk9ns) as @NedBatchelder talks about what happens during variable assignment, and list mutability in particular.  (In fact, I find myself rewatching from time to time for the reminders!)

Comment: because `x=[[] for _ in range(3+1)]` creates a new list, and assigns it to the local variables `x`. On the other hand, `x[0]+=1` is actually a mutator method on list objects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Which `mutator method` are you referring to?

Comment: @quamrana `list.__setitem__` will be called as a hook into the indexed, augmented assignment statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code:

```py
def tcheck():
    x=[11,54]
    tcheck2(x)
    q(x)
def tcheck2(x):    
    q(x)
    x[0]+=1 #1
    x=[[] for _ in range(3+1)] #2
    # t+=3
    q(t)
```

Line `#1` just increments an element of `x`. However line `#2` *replaces* the local variable `x` with a brand new `list`.

Perhaps you meant: `x[:] = [[] for _ in range(3+1)] #2` which will update the entire contents of the `list` which `x` refers to.

Comment: I know that but what rule is that, arent the lists or arrays supposed to point to it's reference?

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: @FarhangAmaji there is no special rule here. **All objects** work that way, lists are not special in *any way*. Everything is an object in Python, some objects expose mutator methods, others do not (they are "immutable"). The semantics of assignment are always exactly the same

Comment: btw are variables also objects? they don't follow the rules of arrays or as you said any object based things.

Comment: @FarhangAmaji variables aren't objects, variables *are names that refer to objects*. It doesn't make sense to say "they don't follow the rules of arrays", what does that mean? *There are no special rules for lists* You always use variables as ways to refer to objects.